# The meaning of Xcode hints when crashes occur

Tags: iphone, xcode4, crash

1.When my app crashes and there's no message in console window Xcode shows me a green line with signature EXC_BAD_ACCESS or PROGRAM RECEIVED SIGNAL SIGABRT in the code editor. The question is: does Xcode always put this green line at the line of code where a bug is placed? If i see this green line put at the line

```
[myObject myMethod];
```

may i be confident that the bug should be searched for inside the myMethod function? Or maybe it may mean something else?

2.Sometimes this green line is put inside `main.m` file at the line

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

Do you know what specific about placing the hint there? What does it mean?

3.Also sometimes the strangest thing happens: Xcode shows me a file with assembler code and the green line inside this code. Why? What should i understand when i see that?

4.If i repeatedly do the following: enter a screen, then do something, then quit the screen - my app crashes. It may crash at the second time or at the seventh one. What is the most common  causes for such a crash? A memory leak? But Analyze tells me there are no leaks in my app. What do you think it may be?

Comment: Memory leaks don't cause crashes, they just waste your app's memory.

Comment: ok. so what is the most common cause for a crash? i mean when there's no message in console window about wrong array subscript or unknown selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in another post :

In XCode, go to menu "edit scheme", choose the running configuration and add 'NSZombieEnabled' like in the picture below, when your apps crashes, it will provide you additional infos on the crash that should help you debug it.

[image]

Note that when your application debug is over, remove the NSZombieEnabled command as it impacts the application performances

Comment: Or you can just enable Zombies in the Diagnostic Tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for NSZombies or debug any memory references that you can find in the error message.

You can find some hints here [iPhone Xcode debugging](http://i-phone-dev.blogspot.com/2011/11/debugging-iphone-program-in-xcode.html)

> Regarding (3) I do not think there is a way to interpret that assembly code.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to point 4: The most common cause of a crash accessing deallocated/over-released memory.